# Kotlin Flow On Android: Launch and Merge subflows from Parent

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, kotlin-flow

im loading a Flow> from the database. Based on this result i want to transform each element a with another database call to a Pair.

So basically this:

```
dao.getElementAList().map { list ->
 list.map {elementA -> Pair(it,dao.call2(elementA)) }
}
```

The call 2 returns also a Flow with ElementB. The return type has to be List>.

How can i achive this with the Kotlin Flow API?

Answer (score 0):

## Prerequisite

### Gradle

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.7")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.3.7")
```

### Classes/ Interfaces

```
interface Database {
    fun getElementAList(): Flow<List<Element>>

    fun call2(element: Element): Flow<Call2>
}

class DatabaseImpl : Database {
    override fun getElementAList(): Flow<List<Element>> {
        return flowOf(listOf(Element("1"), Element("2"), Element("3")))
    }

    override fun call2(element: Element): Flow<Call2> {
        return listOf(Call2("c1")).asFlow()
    }
}

data class Element(val s: String) {}

data class Call2(val s: String) {}
```

## Solution

```
dao.getElementAList()
    .flatMapConcat { it.asFlow() }
    .flatMapMerge { e -> dao.call2(e).map { c -> e to c } }
```

NOTE: results are streamed and not emmited at once as a List. If one call fails, all fail.

## Test

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@FlowPreview
@Test
fun sdfdsf() {
    val dao = DatabaseImpl()

    runBlockingTest {
        val result = dao.getElementAList()
                .flatMapConcat { it.asFlow() }
                .flatMapMerge { e -> dao.call2(e).map { c -> e to c } }
                .toList(mutableListOf())

        assertThat(result)
                .containsExactly(
                        Element("1") to Call2("c1"),
                        Element("2") to Call2("c1"),
                        Element("3") to Call2("c1")
                )
    }
}
```